# How to calculate closed form for following pseudocode?

Tags: c++, algorithm, pseudocode

I need help with the following problem:

Analyze the running time of the following program fragment and write pseudocode (in C++) which will output the value of this but which runs in constant time. You may assume that n is given earlier in the program.

```
 sum = 0
 for i from 1 to n-1 do
   for j from i to n*n do
     sum = sum + i
```

What I am up to: I know that the time complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>) for the following program fragment and that the:

```
sum = n*n*(n)*(n-1)/2-(n-1)*n*(2*(n-1)+1)/6+(n-1)*n/2;
```

I am unsure how to put this into pseudocode format. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I don't understand "a pseudocode (in C++)". Usually pseudocode means a separate "language", which doesn't need to be entirely strictly defined as long as the meaning of an algorithm is clear. You could have a pseudocode which looks very similar to C++, but your problem statement uses a common pseudocode style which is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 sum <- n*n*(n)*(n-1)/2-(n-1)*n*(2*(n-1)+1)/6+(n-1)*n/2
```

That's all. There is no need in loops when you know closed-form formula.

Calculation with such formula has constant time complexity